# Keras model doesn't learn at all

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

My model weights (I output them to `weights_before.txt` and `weights_after.txt`) are **precisely** the same before and after the training, i.e. the training doesn't change anything, there's no fitting happening.

My data look like this (I basically want the model to predict the **sign** of feature, ***result* is 0 if feature is negative, 1 if positive**):

```
,feature,zerosColumn,result
0,-5,0,0
1,5,0,1
2,-3,0,0
3,5,0,1
4,3,0,1
5,3,0,1
6,-3,0,0
...
```

Brief summary of my approach:

1. Load the data.
2. Split it column-wise to `x` (feature) and `y` (result), split these two row-wise to `test` and `validation` sets.
3. Transform these sets into `TimeseriesGenerators` (not necessary in this scenario but I want to get this setup working and I don't see any reason why it shouldn't).
4. Create and compile simple `Sequential` model with few `Dense` layers and `softmax` activation on its output layer, use `binary_crossentropy` as loss function.
5. Train the model... **nothing** happens!

Complete code follows:

```
import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(570)

TIMESERIES_LENGTH = 1
TIMESERIES_SAMPLING_RATE = 1
TIMESERIES_BATCH_SIZE = 1024
TEST_SET_RATIO = 0.2  # the portion of total data to be used as test set
VALIDATION_SET_RATIO = 0.2  # the portion of total data to be used as validation set
RESULT_COLUMN_NAME = 'feature'
FEATURE_COLUMN_NAME = 'result'

def create_network(csv_path, save_model):
    before_file = open("weights_before.txt", "w")
    after_file = open("weights_after.txt", "w")

    data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

    data[RESULT_COLUMN_NAME] = data[RESULT_COLUMN_NAME].shift(1)
    data = data.dropna()

    x = data.ix[:, 1:2]
    y = data.ix[:, 3]

    test_set_length = int(round(len(x) * TEST_SET_RATIO))
    validation_set_length = int(round(len(x) * VALIDATION_SET_RATIO))

    x_train_and_val = x[:-test_set_length]
    y_train_and_val = y[:-test_set_length]
    x_train = x_train_and_val[:-validation_set_length].values
    y_train = y_train_and_val[:-validation_set_length].values
    x_val = x_train_and_val[-validation_set_length:].values
    y_val = y_train_and_val[-validation_set_length:].values


    train_gen = keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(
        x_train,
        y_train,
        length=TIMESERIES_LENGTH,
        sampling_rate=TIMESERIES_SAMPLING_RATE,
        batch_size=TIMESERIES_BATCH_SIZE
    )

    val_gen = keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(
        x_val,
        y_val,
        length=TIMESERIES_LENGTH,
        sampling_rate=TIMESERIES_SAMPLING_RATE,
        batch_size=TIMESERIES_BATCH_SIZE
    )
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(TIMESERIES_LENGTH, 1)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

    for item in model.get_weights():
        before_file.write("%s\n" % item)

    model.compile(
        loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
        optimizer="adam",
        metrics=[keras.metrics.binary_accuracy]
    )

    history = model.fit_generator(
        train_gen,
        epochs=10,
        verbose=1,
        validation_data=val_gen
    )

    for item in model.get_weights():
        after_file.write("%s\n" % item)

    before_file.close()
    after_file.close()

create_network("data/sign_data.csv", False)
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your snippets seems fairly big, can you comment them a bit and/or explain what you're doing from a theoretical point of view?

Comment: I have added a summary.

Comment: Isn't that the issue is with your window length (`length`) set to 1? It seems like you're not providing much of a sequence to learn from.

Comment: Since the result to be predicted is the sign of immediately preceding feature, I think window length 1 is sufficient. Anyway, I have tried length 10 and 100, the problem stays the same. Window length is not the problem IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `softmax` as the activation function of last layer. Essentially, softmax normalizes its input to make the sum of the elements to be one. Therefore, if you use it on a layer with only one unit (i.e. `Dense(1,...)`), then it would always output 1. To fix this, change the activation function of last layer to `sigmoid` which outputs a value in the range `(0,1)`.