# Untrained binary classification keras model gives output of 1 on all

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to build a small neural net with one hidden layer. I would expect that before training, the model would output random-looking values. But for all inputs, I get 1.0 as the output. Why woudl that be?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

def NewModel():
  return keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(20, input_shape=(18,), activation=tf.nn.relu, name="inputLayer"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name="outputLayer"),
    ])

model = NewModel()
i = np.array([[0.2]*18])
print(model.predict(i))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras model doesn't learn at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876097/keras-model-doesnt-learn-at-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use softmax with a single output neuron, because it normalizes by dividing by the output of all neurons, and this produces a constant 1.0 value, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks. My sleep deprived brain thought I was using sigmoid activation...

Comment: Hi Matias, could you please go to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/recurrent-neural-network/synonyms) and vote for making "rnn" a synonym of "recurren-neural-network" (of course, if you are agreed with this synonym proposal)? Thanks.